# How to Parse P12 File

Tags: certificate, key, pkcs#12, pkcs#7, pfx

I'm writing a parse tool to extract each field of P12 file in C language, OpenSSL is too huge for my project.
After reading PKCS# series documents and ASN.1 documents, I understand the basic parse step.
I use OpenSSL to generate a self-signed P12 file，there're some questions during parsing:

1. Why Certificate is not stored in a Safebag, in my case it's stored in EncryptedData field?
2. What does the localKeyId attribute mean? it has an OctetString, what is the OctectString used for?
3. Why the contentType of encryptedContentInfo is id-data? I think it should be id-encryptedData. In my case, Certificate is stored in encryptedContentInfo field.
   [image]

Thanks,
CZ

Comment: What do you mean by "too huge"? libssl is about 3MB in size.

Comment: This is a pure programming question. Better would be to ask it at SO.

Comment: @MechMK1, the MCU we use only have 1M memory. we want to parse P12 file in an embedded system.

Comment: @mentallurg, P12 file is a security related document. that's why I ask questions here. I hope some expert could help me.

Comment: Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40157/parsing-of-x-509-certificates

Comment: @mti2935, thanks for the reference. I know how to parse x.509 certificate. Now my question is how to parse P12 file. It's different.

Answer (score 0):

The PKCS12 standard [also available as rfc7292](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7292) formally allows a very wide range and combination of options, but in practice only a few of these options are used. There are basically 3 levels:

1. the file has type/structure PFX consisting mostly of a PKCS7/CMS ContentInfo which theoretically can be 'data' or 'signed-data' but in practice is always the former (with the nominally optional MacData appended) and contains
2. 'AuthenticatedSafe' which is a sequence of one or more (almost always more) ContentInfo(s) each of which (separately) may be encrypted or not and contains (after decryption if applicable)
3. a sequence of one of more 'bag'(s) each of which contains actual data of a certain type such as an encrypted privatekey or a certificate along with optional attributes.

In practice there is usually:

- one CI (at level 2) with PKCS7/CMS type 'encrypted-data' using a very weak algorithm (RC2-40) containing one or more CertBag(s) each containing a cert plus any attributes for it, and
- one or more CI(s) (each) with type 'data' containing a PKCS8ShroudedKeyBag containing an encrypted privatekey (using PKCS8 as stated) usually using a strong algorithm commonly 3DES, plus attributes.

[My answer here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/203377/39571) shows the first levels of parsing to find the encryption details; further parsing requires decryption as shown (for a specific case) in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242721/openssl-debugging-how-to-dump-intermediate-asn-1-inside-openssl).

As mentioned all bags can have attributes; in practice depending on the implementation some bags may have the 'friendlyName' attribute with a value intended for people to use, and if a matching privatekey and cert are present they both have a 'localKeyId' attribute with the same value to tie them together, as explained in [my answer to a different but related Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932436/why-openssl-pkcs12-in-keystore-p12-out-client-certificate-pem-clcerts-nokey). 'localKeyId' is not intended for people to use and you should not normally present it to people.

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation. I think you answered my 2nd question. But still I don't know why the certificate is not stored in a Safebag, instead it stored in "EncryptedData" field. As PKCS#12 defines "A CertBag contains a certificate of a certain type".And how to determine the ContentType is id-data or id-encryptedData?

Comment: In practice the encryptedContenInfo's ContentType(for certificate) is set to id-data, not id-encryptedData. the ContenType for PrivateKey is set to id-data. I'm really confused.

Comment: After reading PKCS#12 again, now I understand the ContentType filed meaning at each different level. if authSafe.ContentType is id-data, it means macData field is present, otherwise macData field is absent. if ContentInfo.ContentType is id-data, it means the following content it not encrypted; if ContentInfo.ContentType is id-encryptedData, it means the content will follow "EncryptedData" definition. and encryptedContentInfo．contentType field  is fixed as id-data(refer to section 5.1, PKCS#12).

Comment: I'm wandering why certificate is not put in a SafeBag, is it because the security reason. As the definition of CertBag doens't include any encryption. How do you think?   CertBag ::= SEQUENCE {
certId BAG-TYPE.&id ({CertTypes}),
certValue [0] EXPLICIT BAG-TYPE.&Type ({CertTypes}{@certId})
}

Comment: Every real bag, including CertBag, _is_ an instance of SafeBag, and every SafeBag is in what I call a level-2 ContentInfo. Are you asking why CertBag isn't encrypted at bag level (like PKCS8ShroudedKeyBag is), or why the ContentInfo containing the CertBag _is_ encrypted -- with an algorithm that was weak even in 1996? I don't have direct knowledge that far back, but my guess would be that's what Microsoft did, and everybody else just copied them because "don't fix it if it ain't broken".

Comment: I'm asking  why CertBag isn't encrypted at bag level (like PKCS8ShroudedKeyBag is). In my case certificate is encrypted, so I guess that's why it can't put in CertBag.